# Docker app deployment hangs on Marathon, fails on Mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm attempting the (potentially foolish) task of Dockerizing Zookeeper/Marathon/Mesos and deploying Docker containers *from* the Dockerized Mesos cluster.

So far, I have a working Mesos cluster on two physically separate nodes: one node is running both a Mesos [master](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/magsol/lj-mesos-master/dockerfile/) and a [slave](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/magsol/lj-mesos-slave/dockerfile/) (container Dockerfiles linked), and the second node is running just a slave. They seem to be functioning just fine; I am able to submit very simple jobs through Marathon (also its own container, running on the node with the master and slave) and they complete successfully.

However, when I attempt to [submit Docker containers through the Marathon API](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html), it *seems* to hang. The Marathon interface hangs at "Deploying" and never changes, even after letting it sit for 15 minutes, stopping, resubmitting, and letting it sit for another 15 minutes.

[image: Marathon UI, depicting seemingly frozen deployment of Docker task]

At the same time, tasks are nonetheless being submitted to the Mesos slaves; the Mesos UI is reporting FAILED tasks left and right.

[image: Mesos UI, depicting failed tasks]

***EDIT 1***

The resulting Sandbox logs for each of the executors are also completely empty.

[image: empty sandbox]

***EDIT 2***

Found something interesting buried in the slave logs:

[image: slave logs]

Line of interest:

> None of the enabled containerizers (mesos) could create a container for the provided TaskInfo/ExecutorInfo message.

It looks like the containerizer is failing to run, and from what I can see, it's not even considering docker as a containerizer. I followed the configuration [here](https://open.mesosphere.com/tutorials/launch-docker-container-on-mesosphere/) to deploy Docker jobs; does this change if the Mesos slaves are themselves Docker containers?

I'm somewhat out of my element and can't find any references along these lines. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: To help you triage the problem, task logs are essential. You can get them from the WebUI by clicking on the sandbox link.

Comment: Unfortunately the Sandbox links report "No files" in any of the respective directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's your `docker run` command for the slave?
Here are a few parameters others have found useful:

> ```
> --net host \
> --pid host \
> --privileged \
> --env MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos \
> --env MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=5mins \
> -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
> -v /sys:/sys:ro \
> -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro \
> -v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02:ro \
> -v /home/core/.dockercfg:/root/.dockercfg:ro \
> ```

Also note that you shouldn't name the container `mesos-slave` as the slave will try to remove any containers prefixed with `mesos-` upon recovery.

FYI, Mesos uses the `docker --version` command to see if the docker containerizer can be used. Try launching a Marathon task that just runs `docker --version` to see if that would work inside your dockerized slave's environment.

Comment: I discovered through extensive googling around that there are two key configuration lines (which are included among those you posted): `-v /sys:/sys` and `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. Including those two lines made everything work perfectly. I'm glad to have it working, but if you have any information pertaining to what those options do (i.e. *why* they fixed this problem), I'd love to hear it!

Comment: For reference, this is the `run` invocation I'm now using: https://github.com/magsol/littlejohn/blob/master/dockerfiles/lj-mesos-slave/start.sh

Comment: @Magsol I can't seem to figure out where you enter these configuration? Are you running Mesos master and slave nodes inside docker as well?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin Yes, the entire framework is Dockerized: Mesos inside Docker, which spins up Docker images.